# A bag contains 4 black balls and 4 white balls. Suppose one draws two balls at a time, until the bag is empty...

Tags: probability

**Question:** A bag contains 4 black balls and 4 white balls. Suppose one draws two balls at a time, until the bag is empty. What is the probability that each drawn pair is of the same color?

I have been provided a solution, but I find it difficult to understand. If someone could decipher it for me it would be greatly appreciated.

**Background information:** order is not important so we use the formula: 
$$n!\over (n-r)!r! $$ which is also written in the notation: $$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        n \\
        r  \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
where n is the total number of elements, and r is the elements we draw from it
For example, if we wanted to know how many combinations of 2 there were in 5 elements, we'd use n=5 and r=2.

**Given solution**

1) The number of such doubly unordered outcomes S is:
$$ {1\over4!} * \begin{pmatrix}
        8 \\
        2  \\
        \end{pmatrix} * \begin{pmatrix}
        6 \\
        2  \\
        \end{pmatrix} * \begin{pmatrix}
        4 \\
        2  \\
        \end{pmatrix} *
     \begin{pmatrix}
        2 \\
        2  \\
        \end{pmatrix}
 = {1 \over4!}*{8!\over2!6!}
*{6!\over2!4!}
 * {4!\over2!2!}
 * {2!\over2!0!} = {1\over4!}{8!\over(2!)^4} = 105$$

2) The number of such outcomes with pairwise the same color is
$${1\over2!} 
\begin{pmatrix}
        4 \\
        2  \\
        \end{pmatrix}
    \begin{pmatrix}
        2 \\
        2  \\
        \end{pmatrix} 
* {1\over2!} 
\begin{pmatrix}
        4 \\
        2  \\
        \end{pmatrix}
    \begin{pmatrix}
        2 \\
        2  \\
        \end{pmatrix} = 3 * 3 = 9$$

Thus, the probability each pair is of the same color is 9/105 = 3/35

My main confusion stems from the initial $1\over4!$ where does that come from? Similarly, the ${1\over2!}$ in step 2. Other than that, I grasp step 1, in step 2 I'm unsure of why we have to multiply the equation by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $\binom{8}{2} \cdots \binom{2}{2}$ counts the number of *ordered sequences* of *four unordered pairs* you could get. However, they don't want to account for the ordering of the four pairs, so they divide by $4!$. [This is what they mean by "doubly unordered."] Alternatively, you can think of part 1 as counting "how many ways can you divide the 8 balls into 4 groups?" An equivalent computation is $\frac{8!}{(2!)^4 4!}$, which can be interpreted as first counting the $8!$ ways to line up the balls, dividing by $2!$ for each pair to account for the ordering within the pair, and then dividing by $4!$ to account for the ordering of the four pairs.

In step two, $\frac{1}{2!} \binom{4}{2} \binom{2}{2}$ counts the number of ways to divide the four black balls into two groups of two. (The same argument as for part 1 can be used to derive this.) You have to multiply this whole expression by itself because you need to also count the number of ways to divide the four white balls into two groups of two.

Comment: Thanks for great explanation! I understand now.

Answer (score 1):

I don't get the 9 count of pairwise balls of same color. To me 9 seems wrong. I can count 6 pairs and not 9:

B B W W, B W B W, B W W B, W B B W, W B W B, W W B B

where B stands for 2 black balls, W for 2 white balls. So to me the response from @angryavian is not correct.

Comment: Each of those has probability $\frac{4! \,4!}{8!}=\frac1{70}$, giving the same total probability of $\frac{3}{35}$ as before.  But they are decidedly ordered and the question was about an unordered count